# How to Install Xnee in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I tried to install and try sample xnee using [this Xnee Guide](https://xnee.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/xnee1.pdf).

I downloaded xnee-3.19.tar.gz and did the following steps

```
gunzip xnee-3.19.tar.gz
tar xvf xnee-3.19.tar
cd xnee-3.19
./configure
make clean all
sudo su
make install
```

Then I tried to run the following

```
cnee --record -o example2.xnr --device-event-range 2-3 \ --time 5 --events-to-record 20
```

But it shows `-bash: cnee: command not found`

Then I installed Xnee-libs-3.19-1.el6.x86_64.rpm and Xnee-3.19-1.el6.x86_64.rpm then I tried the same cnee command but again it shows same error.

How to install Xnee in linux and execute?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're removing all executables prior to copying anything. and you don't compile then back afterwards

`make clean all` removes what was compiled previously

Instead your process should look like

```
./configure
make 
sudo su
make install
```

Here's pretty good document on `make` files [document](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_2.html)

Comment: `make install` shows on screen steps it's doing. One of these steps is to copy file called cnee to some directory. Check that directory for file presence and if it's there then make sure the directory is added to $PATH variable